# Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM exception in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have created a code for deleting a particular row from an Excel table using OLEDB connection pool in asp.net with c#.

I took a GridView in design mode and wrote the delete code on the *RowDeleting* event of it.

It throws exception **Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM** when I click on auto-generated *Delete* button.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string txt1 = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(con_string);

    string qry = "delete from [Sheet1$] where [id]='"+txt1+"'";
    OleDbCommand omd = new OleDbCommand(qry,con);

    con.Open();
    omd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: update all row's fields to empty values, then filter your select query. see my detailed answer below. u can't delete... u can "simulate" a delete.

Answer (score 2):

OLE DB provider only allows to insert or update records to excel sheet. It does NOT allow delete operations.

Comment: so what should i use for deleting the rows in excel sheet

Comment: U can't. Only the workaround is dropping the sheet, repopulating with other records except the record u intend to remove. Not a good idea.

Comment: The only alternative is using Excel interop to remove the whole row

Answer (score 1):

You can`t delete rows using OLEDB with Excel.

The workaround is to UPDATE de whole row, setting field='' for every single field of the row.
Something like:

```
UPDATE [customers$A1:D50] SET customerID='', companyname='', contactname='', address='' WHERE customerID='123'
```

Afterwards, to get ride off those empty rows, simply use something like `WHERE customerID <> ''` in SELECT clauses